# KeyError: 'iris'

Tags: python

I'm getting these errors for my Python IDLE Shell code. I have the iris.csv file in the same place as the Lab 5.py file, so I'm not sure what to do next. A fix would be greatly appreciated!

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kyle_\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3800, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 165, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5745, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5753, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'iris'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kyle_\OneDrive\Documents\COIS 4400H\Lab 5.py", line 23, in <module>
    iris_df['iris'].drop_duplicates()
  File "C:\Users\kyle_\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\kyle_\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3802, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'iris'
>>>
```

This is the code I'm using:

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

import datetime as dt

import sklearn
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score

from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import cut_tree

import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\kyle_\OneDrive\Documents\COIS 4400H')
iris_df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')

iris_df.head()

iris_df['iris'].drop_duplicates()

iris_df = iris_df.drop('iris',axis=1)

scaler = StandardScaler()

iris_df_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(iris_df)
iris_df_scaled.shape

sse = []
range_n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9 , 10 ]
for num_clusters in range_n_clusters:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=num_clusters, max_iter=50)
kmeans.fit(iris_df_scaled)

sse.append(kmeans.inertia_)

plt.plot(sse)

# 1. Kmeans with k=3
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=3, max_iter=50)
y = kmeans.fit_predict(iris_df_scaled)

y

iris_df['Label'] = kmeans.labels_
iris_df.head()

plt.scatter(iris_df_scaled[y == 0, 0], iris_df_scaled[y == 0, 1], s = 100, c = 'purple', label = 'Iris-setosa')
plt.scatter(iris_df_scaled[y == 1, 0], iris_df_scaled[y == 1, 1], s = 100, c = 'orange', label = 'Iris-versicolour')
plt.scatter(iris_df_scaled[y == 2, 0], iris_df_scaled[y == 2, 1], s = 100, c = 'green', label = 'Iris-virginica')

# 2. Hierarchical clustering
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
mergings = linkage(iris_df_scaled,method='complete',metric='euclidean')
dendrogram(mergings)
plt.show()

cluster_hier = cut_tree(mergings,n_clusters=3).reshape(-1)

iris_df['Label'] = cluster_hier
iris_df.head()

plt.scatter(iris_df_scaled[cluster_hier == 0, 0], iris_df_scaled[cluster_hier == 0, 1], s = 100, c = 'purple', label = 'Iris-setosa')
plt.scatter(iris_df_scaled[cluster_hier == 1, 0], iris_df_scaled[cluster_hier == 1, 1], s = 100, c = 'orange', label = 'Iris-versicolour')
plt.scatter(iris_df_scaled[cluster_hier == 2, 0], iris_df_scaled[cluster_hier == 2, 1], s = 100, c = 'green', label = 'Iris-virginica')
```

Comment: It looks like your error is here: `iris_df = iris_df.drop('iris',axis=1)`. Are you sure `iris_df` contains this keyword?

Comment: This is Python code.  There is no such thing as 'IDLE Shell code' other than the Lib/idlelib/pyshell.py source for Shell itself.